# Remove image caption from post excerpt on blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

Please find below the javascript that I´m using to generate post summaries (excerpts) on my blogger's blog. Can someone  help me add extra code to it, to avoid including the image captation on the summary/excerpt? I didn´t find solutions on the web for BLOGGER...

```
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){ 
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    {
        var s = strx.split("<"); 
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
            } 
        } 
        strx =  s.join(""); 
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...'; 
}

function createSummaryAndThumb(pID, pURL, pTITLE){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if(img.length>=1) { 
        imgtag = '<span class="posts-thumb" style="float:left; margin-right: 10px;"><a href="'+ pURL +'" title="'+ pTITLE+'"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" class="pbtthumbimg"/></a></span>';
        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a demo blog on which you are using this template ? Also by caption you are referring to the text that comes on hovering the image or which is already present ?

Comment: my blog is: alegadamene.pt    by captation I mean the text that is present on screen, normally immediatly below the photo.